# Ideas for converting dining table to adjustable height coffee table

Tags: wood, furniture, design

I have an old 3'x5' dining table sitting in the garage. I think it would be perfect to go in our den as a large coffee table so my wife can do her huge 3000 piece puzzles up there.

The legs are detachable, so it should be easy to just chop off the bottoms to get to coffee table height.  What I'd really like to do is have the height be adjustable so it can go between coffee table, mid-height for board games etc in front of a shortish couch, and up to dining table height.

I know a thing or two about metal work, but almost nothing about woodwork, so I'm hoping for something fairly simple. I don't need the height adjustment to be continuous or even particularly easy.  My thought was to:

- chop off the bottom ~6" of each leg and then cut that in half.
- drill a hole in the ends of each piece
- attach the pieces together with threaded rod

Then adjusting the table height would involve screwing the bottom sections on or off one at a time. As a bonus I should be able to use that to level the top too.

Questions:

- Is this a sensible way to do things? The legs are straight vertical, so there shouldn't really be any horizontal forces on anything.
- Can I just use a drill press for the center holes, or do I need to remind myself how to use a lathe?
- Any rule of thumb for picking the rod (material, thickness, threading)
- What's the best way to attach the rod? I was thinking to tap the wood itself, then glue the rod into the bottom pieces.  Would something like a nut make more sense? If so, how do I attach the nut? (epoxy?)
- Is there a completely different better way to do this?

Comment: It is really very subjective at this point.
One thing I would caution, if the legs are not round, threading them back together will make it very difficult to have the two sections line back up exactly when the threads bottom out. You will want to account for this if your goal is to tighten them all the way down and have the legs line back up.
Also, making two parts line up with a single drilled hole in each can be tricky. A drill press will work, but you want to make sure you are drilling true in the center of the piece, and then use a marking pin to mark the hole in the second piece.

Comment: There are also many examples of tables built using this same concept with hinged legs, as opposed to detachable.

Comment: @JacobEdmond: The legs are round, so that's at least one thing I don't have to worry about.  I don't have the imagination to see how you would do something like this with hinged legs. Is the hinge at the top so the legs go at an angle? Or would it still be segmented, just with the bottom pieces folding out of the way rather than being completely removed?

Comment: Yes, with the bottom pieces folding out of the way, but that is usually with square or rectangular profile legs. I think you are on track with an idea that would work.

Comment: What about using the metal rods which slide one inside the  other with the spring locking pin for an adjustable height?  Cut the legs down a bit and use these to adjust the length.  Also, maybe consider making a square block at the top of each leg and mounting them such that the top can hinge on the legs a bit?  Include a cross brace from front to back leg on each side to keep the legs parallel.  This would allow for a tilted top like a writing desk?  OK, overthinking here...

Comment: Using your thoughts, you can tap the wood .  There are [threaded inserts](http://www.woodmagazine.com/materials-guide/fasteners/tips-on-using-threaded-inserts/) and I know I have seen bolts for this where the thread on one side is a screw thread and the other is a machine thread made just for the purpose you are describing.  I believe these, they have opposing threads.

Comment: I'd want to use threaded inserts to avoid eventually tearing out or wearing down the wood from metal-on-wood contacts.

Comment: Mammoth job answering each of the sub questions here as fully as SE format strives for. But after a quick read through of what you want I have a simpler solution than any — **make a set of legs for each working height you want**. This is the strongest option as far as I can see, won't require any monkeying about drilling holes dead centre and then installing screws (even after that threading two sections together dead in line can be a nightmare!) and overall may be the fastest to make, and implement each time.

Comment: @Karl_S: Threaded insets definitely look like the right answer if I go the center-drill approach.  This is a pretty heavy table, not sure a locking pin is strong enough, unless I'm visualizing something different than what you're saying.

Comment: @Graphus: The legs are removable, but it requires flipping the table over and getting to some hard to reach bolts, not something I want to do often.

Comment: See http://legsandbases.com/legs/posts/233 for a leg with a locking pin.  Not a great picture but you may get the idea  I am used to seeing these in folding table legs. Maybe replace the legs with somethimg like the ones at the link?

Comment: "Re-engineer" the leg fixing so that the legs can be swapped out more easily :-) We'd need to see photos to be able to advise on this option should you need help on how you might do this, but with most modern tables it should be very straightforward. For example a single bolt could hold each leg in place, locked with a wing nut inside so no need to even go looking for a spanner. You would need to flip the table, but I think you'd have to do that with any other option too so you've lost nothing there and this way is far simpler than modding the existing legs to make them adjustable.

Comment: Be aware, if the legs happen to be tapered, that cutting them off in a couple of places will cause the remaining pieces that are to be joined back together piecemeal to be slightly different diameters at the mating surface (unless you use the mythical zero-kerf saw to cut them :)

Comment: This question needs to be edited significantly. In it's current form it is a call for a brainstorming session which is outside the scope of this site. While I'm a fan of helping out on this project, it's already turning into an open forum type conversation without a concise question and therefore no clear road to an answer.